# how to write unit test for this property status, interfacing implementation in test class will not work

Tags: c#, .net

```
public Brush Status
{
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("StatusOne");
    }
    get
    {
        return _statusOne;
    }
}
```

where brush is class type defined in system.windows..media.brush
statusOne is returned to the  switch case where operation is done

Comment: What's the actual problem you are having with unit testing this property? Btw, you are setting and getting different fields.

Comment: Are you asking how write a unit test for a method which in turn relies on an interface (that needs to be abstracted away in order to be tested)?